# How to make a right date type for Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR?

Tags: label, titanium, autolink

I had defined a Label with a date text value to test the property `Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR` of `autoLink`,however it doesn't work. I am wonder there're must have some rules to write a formated date text value. Anyone have a good idea? Here is my code: (Running in Mac OSX,Platform:Android,Titanium SDK:3.5.1.GA)

*test.xml*

```
<Label id='test_label'>2015-09-10 14:00:00</Label>
```

*test.tss*

```
"#test_label":{
  width:'100%',
  height:'5%',
  autoLink:Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR
}
```

Comment: For which platform you are using this property ? android or iOS?

Comment: **Running in Mac OSX, platform iOS, titanium SDK 3.5.1.GA** Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry I had not read the Titanium Docs carefully, the property **Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR** not apply for platform Android, and should be **use with  the property Titanium.UI.TextArea.autoLink  together** in **IOS** or **Windows Phone** plaform.  However, now I am confused to use the property, I am wonder how to use the two properties together to make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR** is only supported in Android for label.
On iOS, autolink is only supported on text areas:
Refer [Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-AUTOLINK_ALL) and [Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-AUTOLINK_CALENDAR)
This is basically exposing a limitation of the native platform -- iOS does not natively support auto link calender in TextField or label.

Comment: I am sorry! The platform is Android ! The computer is Mac, but I had applied the Android SDK to my project. Really sorry I forgot that. Anyway,  I still face the problem, and have no ideas.

Comment: [Titanium.UI.AUTOLINK_CALENDAR](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-AUTOLINK_CALENDAR) refer to the Titanium Doc, the property is no longer apply for Android, only for **IOS** and **Windows Phone**.